# I am trying to convert a report or document(it has client information and doc photos in it) to pdf file, that report should get from a url(input)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi, pdf-generation

In my code, I am using DinkToPdf, IronPdf and also iTextSharp.
PdfSharp and iTextSharp, I got only html content in the pdf

DinkToPdf and IronPdf, I got the initial loading symbol only.

In DinkToPdf, I mention the wkhtmltox file and implemented correctly. Are any other implementations or wkhtmltopdf.exe needed?

And the Controller Action for all, like

```
public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadPdf(string url)
{
// method return type is byte[]
    byte[] pdfBytes = await _claimManager.method(url);  //Refactoring from the layers(Clean Architecture)

    var fileName = $"{DateTime.Now.Ticks}.pdf";
    var filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "generatedPdf", fileName);
    return File(pdfBytes, "application/pdf", fileName);
    
}
```

```
//DinkToPdf
public async Task<byte[]> GenerateAsPdf(string url)
{
    var objectSettings = new ObjectSettings
    {
        WebSettings = { DefaultEncoding = "utf-8" },
        PagesCount = true,
        HtmlContent = await GetHtmlFromUrl(url),
        //HeaderSettings = { Center = "Header Text", FontSize = 10 },
        //FooterSettings = { Center = "Page {page} of {totalPages}", FontSize = 10 },
        //Page = url
    };

    var doc = new HtmlToPdfDocument()
    {
        GlobalSettings = globalSettings,
        Objects = { objectSettings },
    };

    var fileName = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + ".pdf";
    var bytes = _converter.Convert(doc);
    //File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, bytes);
    return bytes;
}

private static async Task<string> GetHtmlFromUrl(string url)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        return await client.GetStringAsync(url);
    }
}
```

```
//IronPdf
try
{
    var renderer = new ChromePdfRenderer();

    renderer.RenderingOptions.PaperSize = PdfPrintOptions.PdfPaperSize.A4;
    renderer.RenderingOptions.MarginTop = 20;
    renderer.RenderingOptions.MarginBottom = 20;
    renderer.RenderingOptions.MarginLeft = 10;
    renderer.RenderingOptions.MarginRight = 10;

    IronPdf.PdfDocument pdf = renderer.RenderUrlAsPdf(url);

    var b = pdf.BinaryData;

    return b;
}
```

```
//PdfSharp returns only html content
try
{
    // Download the content from the URL
    var client = new HttpClient();

    var data =  await client.GetStringAsync(url);

    // Create a new PDF document
    var document = new PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument();

    // Create a page in the document
    PdfPage page = document.AddPage();
    XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);
    // Create a font
    XFont font = new("Arial", 12);
    XTextFormatter tf = new(gfx);
    XRect rect = new(50, 50, page.Width - 100, page.Height - 100);
    tf.DrawString(data, font, XBrushes.Black, rect, XStringFormats.TopLeft);      
    // Save the PDF document to a byte array
    byte[] pdfBytes;
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        document.Save(stream, false);
        pdfBytes = stream.ToArray();
    }

    return pdfBytes;
}
```

Comment: Can you replace the code part `await _claimManager.method(url)` with `await _claimManager.method(url).ConfigureAwait(false)` and test again?